# Aplicaçao bubble sort com vetor aleatorio

Tags: c++

Pessoal alguém pode me ajudar com este código, tenho que utilizar o bubble sort para ordenar um vetor aleatório de n posições, porem não consigo resolver o erro.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int n=100;

int main()
{    int j,aux,i;
    //criando o vetor
    int *A=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    //preenchendo o vetor.
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++, A++)
    {
        *A=rand()%50*10;
    }
    //apontando o vetor para o primeiro elemento.,
    A-=n;
    //imprimindo o vetor.
    cout<<"Vetor aleatorio.";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++, A++)
    {
        cout<< *A<<" "; 
    }
    //ordena o vetor .
    for(i=0; i < (n-1); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < (n-i-1); j++)
        {
            if(*A[j] > *A[j+1])
            {
                aux=A[j];
                *A[j]=*A[j+1];
                *A[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    //imprime o vetor ordenado
    cout<<"Vetor ordenado:\n";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<*A<<" ";
    }

}
```

Comment: A ideia é praticar ponteiros ? Porque incrementar o ponteiro do array no `for` com `A++` para logo a seguir fazer `A-=n;` é despropositado e propicio a erros, sendo essa uma das causas do erro

Comment: mesmo corrigindo o incremento do array, continua com o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Vou assumir que a ideia é praticar a utilização de ponteiros.

Nesse caso faltaram algumas coisas e outras estão incorretas, sendo que o código deveria ficar assim:

```
int main()
{    
    int j,aux,i;
    int *A=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++, A++)
    {
        *A=rand()%50*10;
    }
    A-=n;

    cout<<"Vetor aleatorio.";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++, A++)
    {
        cout<< *A<<" ";
    }
    A-=n; //faltou aqui voltar de novo para trás

    for(i=0; i < (n-1); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < (n-i-1); j++)
        {
            if(A[j] > A[j+1]) //sem *
            {
                aux=A[j];
                A[j]=A[j+1]; //sem *
                A[j+1]=aux; //sem *
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Vetor ordenado:\n";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++, A++) //faltou o A++
    {
        cout<<*A<<" ";
    }

}
```

Retirei os comentários que tinha no código para dar ênfase aos que coloquei face às alterações que fiz.

Os locais em que retirei o `*` como `if(*A[j] > *A[j+1])` não precisam porque ao aceder a uma posição com a notação `[]` já esta a aceder ao valor apontado.

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/PL5Rqy)

A minha sugestão é que não utilize esse padrão a menos que seja por mera prática de ponteiros. Avançar com um ponteiro de um array para a frente no `for` para no fim voltar para trás com `A-=n;` é complicado, obscuro e propicio a erros, como já se deve ter apercebido.

Seguindo esse meu conselho e caso não esteja apenas a praticar ponteiros, sugiro que escreva o programa antes assim:

```
int main()
{
    int *A=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        A[i]=rand()%50*10;
    }

    cout<<"Vetor aleatorio.";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<< A[i]<<" ";
    }

    for(int i=0; i < (n-1); i++){
        for(int j=0; j < (n-i-1); j++){
            if(A[j] > A[j+1]){
                int aux=A[j];
                A[j]=A[j+1];
                A[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Vetor ordenado:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Repare que nesta versão apenas declarei as variáveis onde são estritamente necessárias ao invés de no topo do programa. Isto acaba por simplificar e melhorar a legibilidade do código.

Seria também melhor declarar o array estaticamente assim:

```
int A[n];
```

Mas vou assumir que a declaração no `heap` era um requerimento do programa.

[Veja também esta versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/xlDuLf)